# How to format text like a blockquote within a UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring, core-text

I am trying to familiarize myself with `CoreText` and I started by making my own note taking application.

I have regex in place in conjunction with `AttributedStrings` and am trying to essentially mimic the functionality of the `StackOverflow` text box I am typing in now.

I have all of the common things like:

**bold**

*italics*

## headers

`emphasis blocks`

But I am struggling to make a block quote / code block.

> Something like this where it breaks to its own line and creates a box that goes to the edge no matter how long the text is.

```
And it changes the background color
```

Is this even possible to do strictly using AttributedStrings? I've seen some old examples where HTML / CSS is injected but I was hoping I could accomplish it using some special `NSAttributedStringKey` combination.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Here's a sample playground in Swift 3:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let richText = NSMutableAttributedString()

let chunk0 = NSAttributedString(string: "But I am struggling to make a block quote / code block.\n\n")
richText.append(chunk0)

let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.headIndent = 20
// Note that setting paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent
// doesn't use the background color for the first line's
// indentation. Use a tab stop on the first line instead.
paragraphStyle.tabStops = [NSTextTab(textAlignment: .left, location: paragraphStyle.headIndent, options: [:])]

let chunk1 = NSAttributedString(string: "\tSomething like this where it breaks to its own line and creates a box that goes to the edge no matter how long the text is.\n", attributes: [
    NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle,
    NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.yellow
])
richText.append(chunk1)

let chunk2 = NSAttributedString(string: "\nIs this even possible to do strictly using AttributedStrings?")
richText.append(chunk2)

let textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 120, height: 400))
textView.backgroundColor = .white
textView.attributedText = richText
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = textView
```

Here's the output:

[image: result]

But it's important to keep in mind that `UITextView` is much less powerful (for layout and styling) than a web view. If you want to get fancy (like stackoverflow does with the darker line of color along the left edge of the blockquote box), you should just generate HTML and CSS and use a web view.

Comment: Ahh that's how you use the paragraph styling :) Thanks! Also noticed the options: [:] which i totally didn't think of doing but would be helpful. So double thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible by only `NSAttributedString` (or the new `AttributedString` that came out this year).

[image]

The idea is simple, 2 steps:

1. give the quote paragraph `NSMutableParagraphStyle` with custom `headIndent` and `firstLineHeadIndent` using. It will give the paragraph extra space on the left which can be used to draw a verticle line.
2. draw a verticle bar and background rectangle by subclass UITextView and implement `draw(in:rect)` function. The rect of the paragraph can be found by using a function from UITextView's protocol `UITextInput` called [`position(from:offset:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinput/1614511-position). The drawing can be done by using `CAShapeLayer` and `UIBezierPath` in a similar way to `UIView`'s `addSubview()`